# Using Middle ware cause 404 in Express

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, express-jwt

I'm using express.js with express router. My files look like this:

./Routers
-> api.js

./controllers
-> ApiController.js

inside `api.js` I send the request to the ApiController. It looks like this:

`router.get('/',ApiController.home)`

and inside controller it looks like this:

`exports.home = (req,res,next)=>{res.send('hello') }`

I have a middleware like this:

```
function authenticate(req, res, next) {
    //Some functions here
      next()
    })
  }
```

If I change my controller and add the middleware like this:

```
exports.home = authenticate ,(req,res)=>{res.send('hello') }
```

I'll get 404. Any Idea whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add the middleware when declaring the get router

```
 router.get('/', authenticate, ApiController.home)
```

If you do what you're doing

```
 exports.home = authenticate ,(req,res)=>{res.send('hello') }
```

This is basically saying that exports.home = authenticate and ignores your function that has the res.send. Therefore when you hit exports.home function it will only have a next() and not res.send to client. The next will just make the request pass through and it will hit the last error handler which is returning you a 404 as there was never a response received.